# How to escape commands passed to find with the exec option on Linux

Tags: linux, sed, escaping, find, exec

Let me break down my problem into the simplest example I can.

Create a test file containing one line of text.

```
[root@myserver ] /tmp> echo "test ReplaceMe DoNotReplaceMe" > /tmp/daj.txt
```

We have an existing `find` command that we use to substitute text in all the files that match it (in this example I've simplified this command to only work on one file, and stripped out the other stuff it does).

The problem is that it substitutes "ReplaceMe" everywhere it appears, instead of only when it is a word on its own.

```
[root@myserver ] /tmp> find /tmp/daj.txt -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; sed -e 's/ReplaceMe/#DONE#/gi' "${f#.}" ' \;
test #DONE# DoNot#DONE#
```

I've written a new `sed` command to only substitute "ReplaceMe" when it is a word on its own, but NOT when it is a substring of another word.  The output from this command is correct.

```
[root@myserver ] /tmp> cat /tmp/daj.txt | sed -e 's/\(\W\)\(ReplaceMe\)\(\W\)/\1#DONE#\3/gi'    
test #DONE# DoNotReplaceMe
```

When I try to incorporate the updated `sed` command into the `find` command, it breaks.  It looks like I am hitting an escaping problem, but I haven't managed to solve it by adding extra escaping.

```
[root@myserver ] /tmp> find /tmp/daj.txt -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; sed -e 's/\(\W\)\(ReplaceMe\)\(\W\)/\1#DONE#\3/gi' "${f#.}" ' \;
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `f="/tmp/daj.txt"; sed -e s/(W)(ReplaceMe)(W)/1#DONE#3/gi "${f#.}" '
```

Is there a way to escape my `sed` command so that I can run it via `find`, or do I have to look for an alternative solution?

**Update:** The full `find` command we are running prints out the filename and permissions, and then pipes the output of the `sed` to `md5sum`.  Here's an example of it running and matching multiple files:

```
[root@myserver ] ~> find /tmp -regex '.*daj.*\.txt' -printf '%p %m ' -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; sed  -e 's/ReplaceMe/#DONE#/gi' "${f#.}" | md5sum' \;
/tmp/daj2.txt 644 d52bbd311552234b761bcae694c2055a  -
/tmp/daj.txt 644 d52bbd311552234b761bcae694c2055a  -
```

Comment: Don't experiment with shell scripts while logged in as root; it is dangerous.

Comment: That's a sensible suggestion, but FYI this is just a personal development server that is easy for me to reinstall, and I am editing an existing script that runs as root.  The can of worms about running scripts as root can hopefully wait for another Stackoverflow question... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using `{}` directly in the shell, instead you should be passing the file names in as shell parameters. Also, if you want to limit to whole-word matches then use `\<word\>` for `sed`

#### Update

```
find /tmp -regex '.*daj.*\.txt' -printf '%p %m ' -exec sh -c "sed  -e 's/\<ReplaceMe\>/#DONE#/gi' \$@ | md5sum" _ {} \;
```

#### Output

```
$ find . -regex '.*daj.*\.txt' -printf '%p %m ' -exec sh -c "sed  -e 's/\<ReplaceMe\>/#DONE#/gi' \$@ | md5sum" _ {} \;
./daj2.txt 664 ea324b4721ed037dbc2402ded4446005  -
./daj.txt 664 0bbb9104da99c1c1187a2a35e6ac0e9b  -
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Is there any way to change this command so it runs the exec command on each file in turn, rather than passing all the files to a single sed command?  See updates to the original question for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your question about the escape sequence but does solve the problem. I'd basically use `xargs` with `sed` like this:

```
$ find ~/tmp/data.txt | xargs sed -e 's/\<replaceme\>/1234/'
1234 in this sentance
donotreplaceme in this sentance
$
```

and the contents of data.txt:

```
replaceme in this sentance
donotreplaceme in this sentance
```

Also if you might have filenames with spaces in it using the `-print0` parameter tells find to output the list of files as null terminated strings. Otherwise find will interpret the space in the filename as the end of the the filename. Then when using `xargs` you need to use the `-0` parameter to tell xargs that the input is a list of null terminated strings. Example below:

```
find /somedir -print0 | xargs -0 command
```

Comment: If you're going to use `find` and `xargs` in this manner, I highly suggest you add `-print0` to the end of your find statement and add `-0` to the beginning of your xargs statement so it knows to delimit on NUL. Otherwise, your code will break horribly on files with spaces (among other things).

Comment: @SiegeX: Yes this is true. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: While at it, try `s/sentance/sentence/`.